# Why :locale doesn't work with an absolute path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, locale

I'm in process of applying I18n in my Rails app, so I have a problem with url when path's not relative. It's always stay as default in absolute while works fine when path is relative:

## controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
    if cookies[:locale] && I18n.available_locales.include?(cookies[:locale].to_sym)
      lang = cookies[:locale].to_sym
    else
      lang = I18n.default_locale
      cookies.permanent[:locale] = lang
    end
    I18n.locale = lang

  end

  def default_url_options(options = {})
    {locale: I18n.locale }  
  end

end
```

## config/application.rb

```
I18n.available_locales = [:en, :es]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :en
```

## config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    resources :posts, only: %i[index show]
  end

  get '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
  get '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/")
```

## _header.html.erb

```
<ul>
        <li class="<active' if current_page?(root_path) %>"><%= link_to t("header.home"), main_app.root_path %></li>
        <li class="<%= 'active' if active_page('option1') %>"><%= link_to t("header.about_us"), option1_path %></li>
          <ul class="mobilenav">
            <li><%= link_to t("header.option2"), "/option2" %></li>
            <li><%= link_to t("header.option3"), "/option3" %></li>
            <li><%= link_to t("header.option4"), "/option4" %></li>
            <li><%= link_to t("header.option5"), "/option5" %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Hence when go to root path or option1 path it works when change locale while options 2,3,4 and 5 always stay on default locale:

```
localhost:3000/en/option2
```

My question is: is it possible to change locale when path is absolute or should I change all to relative_path?

Comment: Instead of `/#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ ` you probably mean `Regexp.union(I18n.available_locales)` to produce a usable regular expression.

Comment: I guess when you use a string for the href argument, it does not go through the url helpers to create the right url. You have to use the url helpers always (named routes, `url_for`, etc).

Comment: @tadman thats pretty clever. You have to do `Regexp.union(I18n.available_locales.map(&:to_s))` though as available_locales returns an array of symbols.